# Как предотвратить выполнения кода в нескольких экземплярах запущенной программы?

Tags: c++, c++builder

Создал VCL приложение в С++Builder. На нем лежит кнопка вызывающая диалог печати. Если запущены несколько копий приложения и в одном из них открыт диалог печати, то в остальных копиях диалог печати не открывается и выдается сообщение о том, что принтер занят, как только диалог печати закроется,то в любой одной копии я могу открыть его, а для синхронизации использовать мьютекс обязательно.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Gtx1Click(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
     if(OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, true, "MyMutex")) 
     { 
         int k; 
     } 
     else
     { 
          h=CreateMutex(NULL, true, "MyMutex"); 
          if(h!=NULL)
          { 
              PrintDialog1->Execute(); 
          } 
          int Res = GetLastError( ); 
          if(Res == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) 
          { 
            ShowMessage("Ошибка в имени 'MyMutex' "); 
            Gtx1 ->Enabled=false; 
          } 
     } 
}

void __fastcall TForm1::PrintDialog1Close(TObject *Sender) 
{ 
     ReleaseMutex(h); 
     Gtx1 ->Enabled=true; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам требуется

1. Создать и захватить именованный мьютекс функцией
   `hMutex=CreateMutex(nullptr,TRUE,"NAME");`
2. Проанализировать результат.
3. Если `hMutex != NULL` - это первый экземпляр приложения и кнопки в диалоге можно не блокировать
4. В противном случае - нужно проверить `GetLastError()`. Если эта функция вернула `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` - существует второй процесс, ухвативший мьютекс, кнопки нужно заблокировать.
5. При закрытии диалога нужно освободить мьютекс.

   ReleaseMutex(hMutex); 
   CloseHandle(hMutex);

Comment: а обратно после закрытия диалого то не открывает

Comment: @ВасилийТрофов а при закрытии диалга надо бы и мьютекс закрыть - `ReleaseMutex(hMutex); CloseHandle(hMutex);`

Comment: в первом окне приложения могу открыть и закрыть диалог а во втором уже нет

Comment: @ВасилийТрофов скажите, где вы в моем примере видите упонимание OpenMutex()? Подскажу - нигде. Либо вы сделаете так, как я советую, либо вы получите муру.

Comment: где создавать мьютекс в кнопке?

Comment: @ВасилийТрофов он должен создаваться при открытии окна и освобождаться при закрытии

Comment: не работает такой метод как вы предложили